# Issue with saving an image in magento2

Tags: magento2, database

I have created a module to upload and save images in magento2 backend.

When we upload image for the first time, image gets saved in the backend. But when next time updating another fields and saving the data, image gets deleted from the backend.

Please, any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Please update your code to investigate..

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by removing the unset condition for checking images in the save controller.